Is there any way to create a VPN trough php
I tried using Google's Gemini API, but it is restricted in my country, so the only way to use it would be for all users from my country to use a vpn
I wanted to know if there is any way to bypass that with php, so I can integrate it in my website. It can be of any sort, but preferably a vpn

Isnt the API get called through your server? Is your server also couldnt connect the API?
